# Ionic Firebase push notification issue

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework

I'm using Firebase for push notification. Problem is i want to send push notification for some mobile phones but when i'm sending push notification it will send notification to all installed mobile app

Comment: Get the fcm device token from the devices to which you want to push the notifications and use the tokens as target when pushing new messages.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to [get the mobile token and then store it somewhere on your server](https://github.com/roliod/ioinc-push-notification-setup).

Then you can [send to specific devices](https://github.com/roliod/send-push-notification-using-firebase) using the mobile token.

Just in case, i actually wrote a full guide on how to implement push notifications to your ionic app [here](https://medium.com/@rolandoduberu/how-to-add-firebase-push-notification-to-your-ionic-app-4cc62a9fa62d)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, link only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow, you can improve this answer by taking vital parts of the link and putting it into your answer, this makes sure your answer is still an answer if the link gets changed or removed :)